# Getting data from a browser by screen-scraping

Tags: browser, screen-scraping

I have gone thru several relevant looking questions but they did not contain the answer I am looking for. So, here is my question:

I have several web applications at my workplace, which are written using different frameworks and the authors are long gone to ask for feature updates. Hence I have to go thru the same grueling sequence of actions to get, which amounts to a file size of few kilobytes, everyday.

I tried parsing the page source but the programming technique of the authors were all over the place. Some even intentionally obscure the code to not let the data show as text, and there is no reason for this as the code they wrote is company asset. Long story short, I realized if I can copy and paste the textual content of these pages, I can process that data much easily than parsing the page source to get the text (which is sometimes totally impossible)

So, I am now looking for a browser plug-in (in windows or linux environments) or equivalent text based tools on windows or linux, which will load these pages and save the text on the screen to file(s) when invoked.

Despite how hard I tried, I am coming up empty handed.

I do not want to utilize the services of a third party screen-scraping web site, as the data is company confidential and not accessible by outside parties. Everything has to happen on the client end as I do not have access to the servers these apps are running on (mostly IIS on windows front end and a oracle db at the back end. The middle tier, as I have explained before is anyone's wild guess, ranging from native oracle apps to weblogic to tomcat and to some in house developed java/javascript stuff.

Thanks for all the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for an answer for well over a year, I came to realize, as long as I use windows, a modern version of it that is, autohotkey is my savior.

I open the web page, maximize it, place my cursor (mousemove, x, y) then left click (mouseclick, L) then send ctrl-A followed by ctrl-C.

Voila ! everything is in the clipboard. Then I activate my unix session (winactivate PuTTY) and send appropriate key press commands to launch the editor of my choice (which is vi) and finally send a shift-Insert to paste the clipboard into my document. Then save and exit of course.

As an added bonus, right after my document is saved, I can invoke the script of my choice to parse this file and give me back the portion(s) I am interested in.

I know it is not bullet proof, but for my purpose, it helps to a great extent. As a matter of fact, I can do whatever I want with this method.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/htmlastext.html
Freeware that converts an HTML page to text

Comment: Did you have a personal experience with this one by any chance ? Most independent application just try to strip the html sections of the page source and feed you the rest. My pages are javascript heavy and as I have said, some stuff is obscured intentionally. So far, only way to scrape the screen is to select the text on the browser  window by a mouse and ctrl-c to copy it and then paste it in a notepad session.

Comment: Hi, I have not had personal experience with this.  But thinking through your problem, if the pages are being rendered via Javascript, could something like Greasemonkey allow you to write additional scripts that grab the values from the javascript-populated elements?  Then you could submit the collected values to another web form via Ajax and voila, you've got the data!

Comment: aaah... that greasemonkey script is most probably what I exactly need. Problem is, I am neither fluent in Javascript nor have any knowledge on how to write a greasemonkey script to extract such values. I was hoping, someone else has already done this and I can reuse their work.

Comment: Since each webpage is different, it wouldn't be possible to write a catch-all script to handle this, in my opinion.  You would need to first examine the source of the page in question to identify all html elements which you want to scrape data from, then at that point it would be easy to write a javascript function to extract the data.   Do you have access to the webpage code, so that you could add the jQuery library to the included scripts?  if so, it would be very easy to add a simple $(document).ready function which reads the values and submits them via an $.ajax() call page of your choice.

Comment: Otherwise, greasemonkey would be the way to go.  Just reference the desired HTML elements to retrieve their values or innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Any of links, lynx or w3m will do what you want, they are text browsers and you can dump text from a webpage with, for example:

```
w3m -dump http://www.google.com > g.txt
```

Comment: It would have been what I was looking for but, the pages with code obscurity are spitting out the text that they won't display under a modern browser, making the output useless. Like, there is a page which pulls passwords from a database and spits them out character by character, with unused characters in between. You look at the output on, say chrome, and you see a password that you can highlight and copy with your mouse. When you dump lynx output, what you see is all characters, usable and unusable, rendering the output useless. I think because lynx don't understand javascript and styles.